# Correct way to sentence in multiples querys

Tags: mysql, sql

If i have a easy select with LEFT JOIN like this:

```
SELECT .....
FROM "A" LEFT JOIN "B"
```

Now what is the correct way:

```
1- ON A.id=b.id

2- ON B.id=a.id
```

what happend with both ways. there is any restriction with the order in clausule "ON"??

And if I have a 3º query...

```
LEFT join C
```

What is the correct way to this

```
1- ON A.id=C.id

2- ON B.id=a.id 

3- ON C.id=a.id
```

Please help! its very important

Comment: If you are joining just *two* tables, then either of the first two methods is fine. But you ask it without much efforts... Is this a homework btw?

Comment: no, im learning mysql and I get meny question :P
if I joining more than 2 tables the order its importante or is the same.
I didnt find diferences but i read in other post that its diferent

Answer (score 0):

The "equals" operator, pretty much by definition, doesn't care in which order you compare. If x = y, then y = x.

Stylistically, it may be better to write the comparison in the order that you are joining, so that when someone is reading your code, it's slightly easier to keep track of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, the ordering of the comparisons in an `ON` clause has no effect on the query.

For your second question, the choice of columns used for the comparisons *does* have an effect.  So:

```
FROM a LEFT JOIN
     b
     ON a.id = b.id LEFT JOIN
     c
     ON a.id = c.id
```

is different from:

```
FROM a LEFT JOIN
     b
     ON a.id = b.id LEFT JOIN
     c
     ON b.id = c.id
```

The difference is for ids in `a` that are not in `b`.  The first version finds matching records in `c`.  This version does not.  The `left join` finds no match for those records, so `b.id` is `NULL` and there are no matches.

The second option:

```
ON B.id = a.id
```

is absurd.  It doesn't even mention table `c`, so is equivalent to a `cross join`, under most circumstances.

Comment: yes... the second option was wrong, I would like to write:
ON B.id = c.id